# Integrating Bot with Azure Speech Service Issue

Tags: javascript, frameworks, bots

Speech Service exception while trying to use Azure Speech services on a bot via browser

Getting the following exception while triggering voice recognition on my bot using IE, Chrome and Firefox:
SCRIPT12008: SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 401, Unauthorized
The bot works fine for typed messages but fails when the user clicks the mic icon.
I'm using Directline to communicate with the bot.
Can you plse advise? 
Thx in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="chat-assets/css/botchat-override.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <style> 
          html,body{height: 100%}
      </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #fff; background-image: url('aila-msbot.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-size: 100%; ">

    <div id="bot-holder">   
        <div id="bot-container">
            <div class="bot-header">
                <div class="icon-holder">
                    <div class="icon"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bot-title">Aila</div>
                <a href="javascript:closeChat()">X</a>
            </div>
            <div id="bot"></div>
        </div>
        <a id="bot-minimize" class="hide" href="javascript:startChat();">
            <div class="comment"></div>
        </a>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js"></script>
        <script>
            var user = {
                id: 'User',
                name: 'You'
            };
            var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
                token: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
                user: user
            });

var speechOptions = {
    speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer( { subscriptionKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'} ),

    speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer(
        {
            subscriptionKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
            gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,
            voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'
        })
};

            BotChat.App({
                user: user,
                botConnection: botConnection,
    speechOptions: speechOptions,
                bot: { id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', name: 'Bella' },
                resize: 'detect'
            }, document.getElementById("bot"));
            botConnection
                .postActivity({
                    from: user,
                    name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
                    type: 'event',
                    value: ''
                })
                .subscribe(function (id) {
                    console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
                });

      function closeChat(){
        var chatWin = document.getElementById('bot-container');
        var closeIcon = document.getElementById('bot-minimize');
        chatWin.classList.add('hide');
        closeIcon.classList.remove('hide');
      }
      function startChat(){
        var chatWin = document.getElementById('bot-container');
        var closeIcon = document.getElementById('bot-minimize');
        chatWin.classList.remove('hide');
        closeIcon.classList.add('hide');
      }
      onload = function(){
        //closeChat();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bing Search is obsolete.
The Azure Search usage is the recommend approach but it's is not supported by the botchat.js.
So a migration to the webchat.cs is necessary.
More info at https://www.npmjs.com/package/botframework-webchat